# inserting multiple values from datagridview to database

Tags: datagridview, sql-insert

Can someone help me what is the problem of this code? the problem is "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection." :(

```
 try
            {



                OleDbConnection Con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=..\\MotoFix.mdb;");
                Con.Open();

                for (int i = 0; i < gridViewProduct_1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {


                    OleDbCommand Com = new OleDbCommand() { Connection = Con, CommandText = String.Format("INSERT INTO Transaction VALUES ('{0}' , '{1}' , '{2}' , '{3}' , '{4}', '(5)')", gridViewProduct_1.Rows[i].Cells[11].Value, gridViewProduct_1.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value, gridViewProduct_1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value, gridViewProduct_1.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value, gridViewProduct_1.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value, gridViewProduct_1.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value) };
                    Com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                Con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
```

Comment: Please make sure you got 11 columns in the GridView, looks like that is the problem.

Comment: Yes I know, but still I get an error :(

Comment: You got 12 (sorry for the typo in my previous comment) columns in the grid view? Can you update the question with stack trace? Also try to quick watch each `gridViewProduct_1.Rows[i].Cells[11].Value`

Comment: I already have solve it but the problem now is, it doesn't save in the database. The table is correct and the fields are correct? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < gridViewProduct_Transac.Rows.Count; i++)
  {
   using (OleDbConnection Con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=..\\MotoFix.mdb;"))
      {
      Con.Open();
      string str, strOrders;
      string strTranNo = gridViewProduct_Transac.Rows[ii].Cells[13].Value.ToString();
      string strCustomer = gridViewProduct_Transac.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value.ToString();
      string strReferral = gridViewProduct_Transac.Rows[i].Cells[11].Value.ToString();
      string strCashier = gridViewProduct_Transac.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value.ToString();
      string strOrder = gridViewProduct_Transac.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value.ToString();
      string strQuantity = gridViewProduct_Transac.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
      string strTotal = gridViewProduct_Transac.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value.ToString();
      string strDate = String.Format(gridViewProduct_Transac.Rows[i].Cells[12].Value.ToString(), "mm-DD-YYYY");
      string strprodNo = gridViewProduct_Transac.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
      Com_1.Connection = Con;
      strOrders = @"INSERT INTO [Order] (orderNo, prodCode) VALUES ('" + strOrder + "', '" + strprodNo + "')";
      using (Com_1 = new OleDbCommand(strOrders, Con))
         {
            Com_1.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"orderNo", strOrder);
             Com_1.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"prodCode", strprodNo);
             Com_1.ExecuteNonQuery();
          }
```

I already had solved this problem. this is the code :)